# Gnuplot does not pop up the title(or legends)

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I'm trying to get some eps files from the following lines. The problem is that legend (key) does not pop up when I follow the procedure for making output files. (In my case, \lambda=2 is not shown in ps files.)
Any idea or help will be appreciated.

```
filename0 = sprintf('/home/hyogeon/ETH/ETH_with_Pf.T/result/data_plot/data_plot_result/Fp_index0_%d_%d,000000_%d,000000_%d_sOkP.tex',9, 5 ,2, 10) 
set terminal epslatex size 8, 6 standalone color colortext 10
set output filename0
set xlabel '${\large E}$'
set ylabel '$p$' offset 2
set ylabel rotate by 0
set format '$%g$'
set key at 37, 0.9
filename1 = sprintf('/home/hyogeon/ETH/ETH_with_Pf.T/result/data_refine/p_index0_%d_%f_%f_%d_sOkP',9, 5, 2, 10) 
filename2 = sprintf('/home/hyogeon/ETH/ETH_with_Pf.T/result/data_refine/p_index1_%d_%f_%f_%d_sOkP',9, 5, 2, 10)
color1 = '#FF0000'
color2 = '#FF9933'
plot filename1 u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars pt 6 ps 2 lc rgb color1 title '$\lambda = 2$',\
filename2 u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars pt 6 ps 2 lc rgb color2 notitle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you manually place the key at (37, 0.9), but do not specify the x- and yrange – these are automatically adjusted. Without your data I can't verify, but supposedly your data lies within [-20:20] in x, then your key is placed far outside the graph and therefore not visible.

As a first step you could try deleting the line `set key...`, see whether the auto placement suits you, and only then fine tune it. Or alternatively, explicitly use `set xrange ...` and `set yrange ...`

By the way, you can directly define variables as strings, you don't necessarily need to call `sprintf` (although you might have reasons to do so):

```
filename0 = 'home/hyogeon/ETH/ETH_with_Pf.T/result/data_plot/data_plot_result/Fp_index0_9_5,000000_2,000000_10_sOkP.tex'
```